# How do i solve should trim empty<i> warning in aptana studio?

Tags: html, css, templates, aptana, font-awesome

Just downloaded an online store template, everything works fine except the icons declared as below:

```
<li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>+1 456 6717</span></li>
```

All the CSS files are linked to it and everything looks fine but i get this error (Warning) in Aptana studio.
Should trim empty
Any idea? help please...

Comment: @LeandroSoares read the question first the ask question!

Comment: "but i get this error (Warning) in Aptana studio. Should trim empty Any idea? help please..." Where do you say the error? It's not clear...

Comment: this is the error : "Should trim empty"

Answer (score 2):

This code looks good.
The font-awesome icons should be rendered using empty `i` tag.
Please take a look here for more examples https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples//

You can change settings of Aptana studio
(go to Aptana Studio > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation)

Select HTML Tidy Validator then some collapse-able options will appear. Select Elements, it will show a list of options. Now go to the bottom of the list and you'll see "Trim Empty Elements": change it from Warning to Ignore.

Comment: Is file with this line is .html?

Comment: you mean the line pasted above? if so yes